# ODataConventionModelBuilder with multiple namespaces

Tags: odata

This is either super straight forward, or its relatively easy to answer. I have the following code in order to set up my OData Routing Conventions:

```
// OData
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

// OData entity sets..
builder.EntitySet<Book>("Books");
builder.EntitySet<Shelf>("Shelves");

// Bound Function..has to be located on the Tables Controller...
builder.Namespace = "BookService";
builder.EntityType<Table>().Collection
    .Function("MostRecent")
    .Returns<DateTimeOffset>();

builder.Namespace = "ShelfService";
builder.EntityType<Shelf>()
    .Action("NearestEmptyShelf");
```

...But the problem with this is when the application starts, everything is routed against `ShelfService` rather than the first function being accessible from `BookService.MostRecent` and `ShelfService.NearestEmptyShelf`.

I'm sure others have run into this particular problem when creating services (actions/functions) for their OData Controllers. But I'm just after a definitive answer as to whether or not you can have multiple namespaces in the OData Routing Collection?

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your namespace of `builder.Namespace = "Bookservice";` with `builder.Namespace = "ShelfService";`.

To utilize two separate namespaces you need two separate instances of `new ODataConventionModelBuilder();`

The below is for OData V4

```
// Book OData Endpoint
var book_builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

// Book OData entity sets..
book_builder.EntitySet<Book>("Books");

// Book Bound Function..has to be located on the Tables Controller...
book_builder.Namespace = "BookService";
book_builder.EntityType<Table>().Collection
    .Function("MostRecent")
    .Returns<DateTimeOffset>();
// Book Config
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "OData - Book",
    routePrefix: "book",
    model: book_builder.GetEdmModel()                
    );

// Shelf OData Endpoint
var shelf_builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

// Shelf OData Entity Sets
shelf_builder.EntitySet<Shelf>("Shelves");

// Shelf Bound Function..has to be located on the Tables Controller...
shelf_builder.Namespace = "ShelfService";
shelf_builder.EntityType<Shelf>()
    .Action("NearestEmptyShelf");
    .Returns<whatever you planned on returning>()
//Shelf Config
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "OData - Shelf",
    routePrefix: "shelf",
    model: shelf_builder.GetEdmModel()                
    );
```

It has been a while since I've implemented this mechanism, but you may have to overwrite `AttributeRoutingConvention` to utilize bound functions in multiple namespaces/controllers using the above method. I know I had a hiccup with it at some point and ended up finding a good method on stack overflow for a `public class CustomAttributeRoutingConvention : AttributeRoutingConvention` that utilized a `public static class HttpConfigExt` to provide a `CustomMapODataServiceRoute` to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a crack and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this was answered, but I got into this problem recently and found an alternate solution so there it goes...

```
...
builder.Namespace = "Namespace_A"; // This would be the default namespace
...
function = builder.EntityType<EntityA>()
    .Collection
    .Function("FunctionInNamespace_B")
    .ReturnsCollection<EntityB>();
function.Namespace = "Namespace_B";
```

Absolutely simple and works like a charm.